# Дописывается дополнительная закрывающая скобка в pycharm

Tags: python, html5, pycharm

Я пишу проект в django и мне нужно написать html код.

Проблема заключается в том, что если я пишу в HTML файле в pycharm такие скобки `{}`, то при вводе закрывающей скобки дописывается ещё 1 закрывающая скобка и получается `{}}`

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/completing-punctuation.html

Comment: Я находил эту инструкцию, ничего не меняется, даже если я пишу просто ```}```, то проставляется сразу вторая закрывающая кавычка